# Is the cylinder homotopic to the circle without using real multiplication?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a *nice* topological space (for example $X = \mathbb{S}^1$). It is possible to show by hand that the cylinder $X \times [0,1]$ is homotopic to $X$. All the proof I know rely on the multiplication of two reals.
Since *being homotopic* has an intuitive meaning that do not need multiplication, I would like to see a method that do not use this fact.

Comment: Hint: $[0,1]$ is contractible. The result is true for any topological space.

Comment: @DarthLubinus Right, but that fact uses multiplication $I \times I \rightarrow I$ as the null homotopy.

Comment: That's true... Still, that fact is dependent only on the structure of the topological space $I$, not on $X$.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](https://hub.darcs.net/dolio/agda-share/browse/cubical/Cylinder.agda) a proof using cubical Agda, which is an environment allowing you to do synthetic homotopy. This means that certain principles are directly assumed that characterize homotopy (and make the reasoning itself homotopical), rather than building it out of e.g. real numbers. In the case of Agda, this means one can define spaces in terms of being generated by points and paths between them, and one can talk about points along a path via formal, continuously varying parameters.

A key lemma that the interval is contractible is then:

```
[0,1]-lemma : ∀ i → Path [0,1] zero i
[0,1]-lemma zero = λ k → zero
[0,1]-lemma one  = λ k → seg k
[0,1]-lemma (seg j) = λ k → seg (j ∧ k)
```

Which involves only definition by (coherent) cases, the generating points/paths, and certain operations on the formal parameterization of paths (like being able to take the 'minimum' of two parameters).

If you're interested in this sort of synthetic homotopy, there's [the Homotopy Type Theory book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/).

For a more general explanation of the 'synthetic' method (with an example other than homotopy), there was recently a [nice talk on the subject](http://math.andrej.com/2021/02/03/synthetic-mathematics-with-excursion-to-computability/) by Andrej Bauer.

Comment: Thx it is what I was looking for as a type of result/method